# Build a RDD LabeledPoint from a Spark RDD object on scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I want to build a `RDD[LabeledPoint]` from a `RDD`object, the RDD object is the following :

```
 +-------------------+---------+--------------+--------+-------+
 |          date_time|site_name|posa_continent|year    |label  |
 +-------------------+---------+--------------+--------+-------+
 |2014-08-11 07:46:59|        2|             3|2014    |1      |
 |2014-08-11 08:22:12|        2|             3|2014    |2      |
 |2015-08-11 08:24:33|        2|             3|2015    |1      |
 |2016-08-09 18:05:16|        2|             3|2016    |3      |
 |2011-08-09 18:08:18|        2|             3|2011    |2      |
 |2009-08-09 18:13:12|        2|             3|2009    |1      |
 |2014-07-16 09:42:23|        2|             3|2014    |1      |
 +-------------------+---------+--------------+--------+-------+
```

I want to construct an `RDD[LabeledPoint]` with the `label` attribut in order to apply the KNN machine learning algorithm. I use the Spark Scala API.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to create an array with label values but I think isn't the good method

Comment: what information from your rdd do you want to be included in your labeledPoint?

Comment: I want to include date_time, site_name, posa_continent, year and label as label of the labeledPoint object

Comment: Przemek's answer below gives the basic structure to what you are looking for. However, I doubt that date_time and year (at the very least) will be useful with what you want. You might consider doing some preprocessing with your variables first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `map` function on RDD:

`rddsObject.map(object => LabeledPoint(object.label, Vectors.dense(object.site_name,object.posa_continent,object.year))`